# Custom GIF in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am developing UWP application, to showing loading process i am using a Custom GIF image as usercontrol. I am adding this GIF image user control to a grid like below.
But while running the GIF it hangs some time..But when i use ProgressRing control it is running perfect.

```
 <Grid 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="ProcessingGrid"
                Visibility="{x:Bind VM.IsProcessing ,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">

    </Grid>
```

This is my Usercontrol

```
<Grid
     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">        
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.3">
        </SolidColorBrush>
    </Grid.Background>        
    <Image x:Name="loadingGif" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/GifAssets/ADProcessingIcon.gif" 
               Width="80">
    </Image>        
</Grid>
```

Comment: There's multiple reasons you won't often see animated .gif's in win apps. Most of us (including myself) just convert the gif to XAML instead. Share a copy of the .gif file so I can see the animation and I'll show you how to make it friendlier soon as I get a free moment.

Comment: What is the GIF you are using? Please share the image so that we can know where your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

try using "XamlAnimatedGif" library

```
<page
....
xmlns:gif="using:XamlAnimatedGif"/>

...
<Image x:Name="imgLoading"
gif:AnimationBehavior.SourceUri="/Assets/GifAssets/ADProcessingIcon.gif"/>
...
```